# What is the correct way to add code samples to PHP doc tags?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

The phpDocumentor (https://phpdoc.org) does no specify what is the correct way format inline code samples. I have previously seen:

Doxygen:

```
/**
 * Set a variable like:
 *
 * \code
 * $foo = 'bar';
 * \endcode
 */
```

Go-style:

```
/**
 * Set a variable like:
 *
 *     $foo = 'bar';
 */
```

Java-style:

```
/**
 * Set a variable like:
 *
 * <pre><code>
 * $foo = 'bar';
 * </code></pre>
 */
```

Python-style:

```
/**
 * Set a variable like:
 *
 * >>> $foo = 'bar';
 */
```

I understand that phpDocumentor has `@example` and `@source` but these are just pointers to line number in other files. Inline code snippets are much easier to write and understand.